# Easier way to translate index (0-7) to letters (A-H)

Tags: java

This method is handling the job, but I am sure there must be a better way to do this...?

```
private String posLetter(int posX) {
    String letter = ""; 
    if (posX == 0) {letter = "A";}
    if (posX == 1) {letter = "B";}
    if (posX == 2) {letter = "C";}
    if (posX == 3) {letter = "D";}
    if (posX == 4) {letter = "E";}
    if (posX == 5) {letter = "F";}
    if (posX == 6) {letter = "G";}
    if (posX == 7) {letter = "H";}
    return letter;
}
```

Comment: You'd better use `else if` blocks for all subsequent checks, when you write code like this. You can also improve it by using a `switch` statement or expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to exploit ASCII codes:

```
private String posLetter(int posX) {
    return String.valueOf((char) (65 + posX));
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
String [] arr = {"A", "B", ....}
return arr[posX]
```